# Tikz externalization and global arguments: no update

Tags: tikz-pgf, externalize

Consider the following `TikzExample.tex` example to be compiled via `pdflatex -shell-escape TikzExample`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\definecolor{Diag}{cmyk}{0.84,0,0.05,0.40}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{figure1}
\input{figure1tikz.tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{figure2}
\input{figure2tikz.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where `figure1tikz.tex` is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=Diag!50] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and `figure2tikz.tex` is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red!50] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[Diag,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If the above tikz pictures are changed, then compiling the main document will update the plots. Good! However, changing the global color `Diag` has no effect on new compilations. This makes sense given how externalization works, that is if a tikz file is newer than the main document, then the tikz file is recompiled. How could we ask the system to recompile all plots affected by a global argument like the `Diag` color above? One solution would be to delete all corresponding pdf, I think, but this is not ideal.

Comment: you can always force a remake with the `force remake` key.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good point but it goes slightly against the automatic externalization.

Comment: Sorry but there is no (sensible) way that tikz can look into the pictures and check if they use a specific color. If you change such a global variable you will have to recreate all figures.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Or maybe what could be done is to store all these global variables in a dedicated file and ask tikz to look after possible changes in that file when compiling the main document in a way similar to what it does for actual external tikz pictures??

Comment: Sorry but you know when you change the global variables, so why do you need some complicated system to check this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because instead of a "changing and saying that I have changed", I just want a simple "changing". There is a redundancy in the first mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the generated filenames depend on a hash of the `\meaning` of any macros that you want to use as a dependency. For colour you can use the internal macro `\csname\string\color@<color-name>\endcsname`

Note if you change the color the generated files change, but it doesn't clean up and remove old ones so you will accumulate

```
figure1-31D7BEC4791629B82ADF280BFE7B3E1E.pdf
figure1-334FBFF45DDEC5AE00C91FC51A840D48.pdf
```

unless you periodically delete them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize


\definecolor{Diag}{cmyk}{0.84,1,0.05,0.40}

\edef\Diagsum{\pdfmdfivesum{\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\color@Diag\endcsname}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{figure1-\Diagsum}
\input{figure1tikz.tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{figure2-\Diagsum}
\input{figure2tikz.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would happen if I need to define other global variables like linewidth? Essentially, I would like to globally parameterize all possible graphical aspects of pgfplots in a large document, so that all plots are consistent. It could be gird color, grid size, background color, axis color, axis with, and so on...

Comment: @pluton you just add `\the\linewidth`: a definition like `\edef\Diagsum{\pdfmdfivesum{\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\color@Diag\endcsname \the\linewidth}}`  hashes on the color and linewidth, so you just have to make a hash that specifies all your dependencies as a one-off cost, then if any of them change the hash will change.